# SQL Query to Node Red Line Chart

Tags: sql, sql-server, node-red

I am attempting to query data out of SQL Server and display it as a line chart in Node Red.

My Data from SQL looks like

```
1556029184000   0.0675168918918922
1556029139000   0.0675515463917528
1556029079000   0.0679347826086958
1556029019000   0.0674082568807342
1556028959000   0.0674431818181822
1556028898000   0.0675537634408605
1556028838000   0.0673611111111115
1556028779000   0.0675917431192663
1556028719000   0.06744212962963
1556028659000   0.0673148148148151
```

Left column is a timestamp converted to Epoch and right column is the value to plot.

Node red debug shows this:

```
[{"x":"1556029788000","y":0.06772222222222232}, 
 {"x":"1556029738000","y":0.06855053191489367}, 
 {"x":"1556029678000","y":0.06858333333333343}, 
 {"x":"1556029619000","y":0.06751146788990835}, 
 {"x":"1556029559000","y":0.06805180180180205}, 
 {"x":"1556029499000","y":2.714885321100926}, 
 {"x":"1556029439000","y":11.43350290697674}, 
 {"x":"1556029378000","y":6.6709253246753235}, 
 {"x":"1556029319000","y":0.06748842592592619}, 
 {"x":"1556029259000","y":0.06760714285714318}]
```

Nothing is displayed in the chart. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `node-red-dashboard` sidebar help has a link to the [details](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-dashboard/blob/master/Charts.md#stored-data) the format for passing data to the chart node.

What you currently have is a `msg.payload` that contains an array of objects with `x` & `y` values. These need to be moved to the `msg.payload.data` field as described:

```
[{
"series": ["A", "B", "C"],
"data": [
    [{ "x": 1504029632890, "y": 5 },
     { "x": 1504029636001, "y": 4 },
     { "x": 1504029638656, "y": 2 }
    ],
    [{ "x": 1504029633514, "y": 6 },
     { "x": 1504029636622, "y": 7 },
     { "x": 1504029639539, "y": 6 }
    ],
    [{ "x": 1504029634400, "y": 7 },
     { "x": 1504029637959, "y": 7 },
     { "x": 1504029640317, "y": 7 }
    ]
],
"labels": [""]
}]
```